# How to add dynamically MenuItem in Xamarin AppShell

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want to add dynamically MenuItems in the AppShell page. This means that it is not alsways clear how much MenuItems should be displayed and which names this MenuItems have.

I have this code:

```
 public partial class AppShell : Xamarin.Forms.Shell
    {
        private static MenuItem CreateMenuItem(string title)
        {
            var menuItem = new MenuItem();         
            menuItem.Text = title;
            return menuItem;
        }
        public AppShell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Database db = new Database();
            List<MyMenuNames> myMenuName = db.SelectTableMenuNames().ToList();

            foreach (var code in myschulcode)
            {
                Shell.Current.Items.Add(CreateMenuItem(code.myMenuName));
            }
        }
     }
```

but it always brings me the error when Items.Add:

**System.NullReferenceException:** 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

What is wrong, which object referenc is not set or any other suggestion how to solve my general problem.

Comment: this `this.Items.Add`

Comment: Thank you very much